# Personalization using a Campaign not working

Tags: experience-editor, personalization

I have created a Test Campaign. I am now trying to Personalize a home page component using the Campaign trigger. However the Personalization rule is not firing.
[image]

I can see the campaign has been triggered. Campaign is triggered using the campaign tracking code.
http://habitat.dev.local/?sc_camp=322A72E385B047879F481FB2FE7B7A2D

[image]

Sitecore **8.2 update 1**

**Updating Some Findings**

When I click on **End Visit** and refresh the page again I can see the Component Personalized.

[image]

As per the personalization rule, isn't it should be triggered in ***Current Visit***?

Comment: To echo Andrew's comment, campaigns have worked best for me when triggered from a fresh session (they certainly don't trigger if you just visited the campaign URL a second time). The personalization rule will fire when the campaign is **newly fired**, not after is has already been fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have been working with campaigns in several different environments and have gotten them to work in all of the.  A few things to check the first is the Sitecore logs to see if an error is thrown when you trigger the campaign.   I have seen multiple issues especially if are you running on a CD server and running switch master to web.

The other thing I remember is that this works best when you use a clean session I have seen Sitecore get confused when you visit the page then trigger the campaign.

Comment: Yes, it's working only in clean session.

Answer (score 2):

As a couple of others have mentioned above, campaigns only trigger on the first page of a site visit.  It was actually considered a bug to not have it behave this way and was "fixed" in Sitecore 7.5

"When a visitor triggered a campaign, the system updated the CampaignID for the visit even if the current page was not the first page of the visit. This has been fixed so now the system only sets the CampaignID for the visit on the first page of the visit. If the visitor triggers campaigns on subsequent pages, the campaign events will still be registered, but the system will not change the CampaignID. (389296)"
https://sdn.sitecore.net/products/sitecore%20v5/sitecore%20cms%207/releasenotes/changelog.aspx